# NGINX Load Balancer 403 Error / Invalid Host Specified when using upstream

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup NGINX to load balance a blockchain explorer.  The server block is below.

```
upstream node {
    server 10.10.10.10:35997;
    server 10.10.10.11:35997;
    }

server {
    root /var/www/secure.deeznnodez.com/html;
    index index.html;
    server_name secure.deeznnodez.com;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        
    #listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/secure.deeznnodez.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/secure.deeznnodez.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }

server {
    if ($host = secure.deeznnodez.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
        
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;

    server_name secure.deeznnodez.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }

server {
    listen 35997 ssl;
    server_name secure.deeznnodez.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/secure.deeznnodez.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/secure.deeznnodez.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://node;
        #proxy_redirect off;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        #proxy_http_version 1.1;
        #proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
        #proxy_http_version 1.1;
        #proxy_set_header Connection "";
        }
    }
```

Here is the RAW POST

```
POST https://secure.deeznnodez.com:35997 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent:Fiddler Everywhere
Content-Type:application/json
Host:secure.deeznnodez.com:35997
Content-Length:56

{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 42, "method": "stats.syncInfo"}
```

Here is the RAW response

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2022 21:49:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 23
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

invalid host specified
```

When I change `proxy_pass http://node;` to `proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:35997;` I get a 200 and the POST is successful.  I've tried many different switches that are all commented out right now in the code above.

I'm about 8 hours deep into this issue and figured it was time to ask the experts for help.  Can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it enabling the **proxy_set_header Host**, specifying the backend host value.